# How to get multiple bar plots in R

Tags: r, ggplot2, bar-chart

The data are as follows

```r
df1<-read.table(text=" Fruit1 Fruit2 Frut3 Z1   Z2  Z3  ZQ1 ZQ2 ZQ3
A   A   A   A   A   N   N   A   A
B   A   B   N   A   N   N   A   A
C   D   A   A   N   A   N   A   A
D   C   A   A   N   N   N   A   N
B   A   A   A   A   N   N   N   A
B   C   B   N   N   A   N   N   N
A   C   D   N   A   N   A   N   A
D   B   D   A   N   A   N   N   N
A   A   C   A   N   N   N   A   N",header=TRUE)
```

I want to have THREE plots concurrently, i.e., Z1 and ZQ1 with Fruit1, Z2 and ZQ2 with Fruit2 and Z3 and ZQ3 with Fruit3. 
I want to get three graphs concurrently like this:
[image]

I have used Map, but it does not work:

```
map2(names(df1)[4:6],(df1)[7:9], names(df1)[1:3], ~
                   ggplot(df1, aes_string(x = .x, fill = .y)) + 
                   geom_bar(position = position_dodge()))
```

Can we do it in R?

Comment: Can anyone help to this question, please?

Answer (score 0):

Try the ggarrange() command from the egg package

Comment: I did, it does not work. If it does work for you, can you show me plz

Answer (score 0):

I am not completely sure if my solution is what you were looking for, but I think it might be really close. I recoded some variables using tidyr, stringr and dplyr, in order to use geom_col with a facet_wrap.

```
library(ggplot2)
library(tidyr)
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)

#Your df
df1<-read.table(text=" Fruit1 Fruit2 Fruit3 Z1   Z2  Z3  ZQ1 ZQ2 ZQ3
A   A   A   A   A   N   N   A   A
B   A   B   N   A   N   N   A   A
C   D   A   A   N   A   N   A   A
D   C   A   A   N   N   N   A   N
B   A   A   A   A   N   N   N   A
B   C   B   N   N   A   N   N   N
A   C   D   N   A   N   A   N   A
D   B   D   A   N   A   N   N   N
A   A   C   A   N   N   N   A   N",header=TRUE)

#Change from wide to long format using tidyr
df2<-gather(df1)

#Make a data frame extracting the letters and numbers of the key column (Fruit, Z, ZQ 
#and 1, 2, 3) using stringr
 df2<-data.frame(panel = str_extract(df2$key,"[1-9]"),
            factor = str_extract(df2$key,"[A-z]+"),
            df2)

 #frequency of each letter per panel variable (1,2,3) and factor (Fruit, Z and ZQ)
 df2<-df2 %>% 
   group_by(panel,factor) %>%
   count(value)

 #Make geom_col with a facet_wrap using panel and factor variables
 ggplot(df2,aes(x=value,y=n,fill=value)) + 
  geom_col() +
  facet_wrap(~panel*factor)
```